# Expected response code 250 but got code "554", with message "554 Message rejected | Laravel Using TO Email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication

- Laravel Version: 8.27
- PHP Version `$ php --version`: PHP 8.0.3 (cli)
- Database Driver & Version $ `mysql --version`: mysql  Ver 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

---

**Problem Statement:**

I'm getting **`TO`** email in **`FROM`** email which of course will not be verified in Amazon SES in **`POST`** `password/email`.

---

**Description:**

Let *to@example2.com* will ask for Password Reset Link via email. Generally *from@example1.com* will send password reset link. However, In my case *to@example2.com* is trying to send password reset link to itself.

In Amazon SES we need to verify email to send mail through SES service. So I've verified *from@example1.com*.

> Note: Both domain are different `example1.com` and `example2.com`. `example1.com` is setup on Amazon SES.

---

**Exception:**

> Swift_TransportException (554)

> Expected response code 250 but got code "554", with message "554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region REGION: to@example2.com "

---

**Configuration:**

```
$ php artisan route:list
```

```
+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                                           | Name                               | Action                                                                        | Middleware                                            |
+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|        | POST     | password/email                                | password.email                     | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail         | web                                                   |
```

`App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{

    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;
```

`vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend\SendsPasswordResetEmails.php`

```
namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

trait SendsPasswordResetEmails
{
 

    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateEmail($request);

        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $this->credentials($request)
        );

        return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                    ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($request, $response)
                    : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }
```

`vendor\laravel\framework\src\illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker.php`

```
namespace Illuminate\Auth\Passwords;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker as PasswordBrokerContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use UnexpectedValueException;

class PasswordBroker implements PasswordBrokerContract
{

    public function sendResetLink(array $credentials, Closure $callback = null)
    {

        $user = $this->getUser($credentials);

        if (is_null($user)) {
            return static::INVALID_USER;
        }

        if ($this->tokens->recentlyCreatedToken($user)) {
            return static::RESET_THROTTLED;
        }

        $token = $this->tokens->create($user);

        if ($callback) {
            $callback($user, $token);
        } else {

            $user->sendPasswordResetNotification($token);
        }

        return static::RESET_LINK_SENT;
```

`.env`

```
MAIL_DRIVER="smtp"
MAIL_HOST="test-smtp.region.amazonaws.com"
MAIL_PORT="25"
MAIL_USERNAME="USER..."
MAIL_PASSWORD="PASS..."
MAIL_ENCRYPTION="tls"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="from@example2.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="foo"
```

Comment: Please share more details. If your mailserver rejects that mail, this does not look related to PHP or Laravel to me

Comment: @NicoHaase, I've added my .env you could see my setup is correct.

Comment: That's what I wrote: your setup is fine. You need to ask the admins of the mailserver you are using for a proper rejection reason

Comment: @NicoHaase, Do I need to ask this with AWS. Since, I'm using Amazon SES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like your AWS mailing service or Laravel is not correctly setup

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-554-400-message-rejected-error/

You could try using mailtrap.io out of the box to test stuff.

That kind exception usually raises when the Server that's supposed to send the e-mail is rejecting it. Usually the case for SMTP or AWS SES. There is also a possibility that you're trying to send through an outlook account through SMTP and security policies won't let you send the message.

However if I got this right you want to send emails as if people sent them theirselves. That won't be possible because you don't have the ability to verify all emails. `*@*`

As a solution you can use `reply-to` option, or `no-reply` as the sender if you don't want the user to be able to reply.

If you are not trying to send mail as `to@`, but instead `from@` make sure the MAIL_FROM_EMAIL is correctly set in env.

Emails should not be sent unencrypted

Email ports to use:

```
Protocol    Security Setting    Port Number(s)
SMTP (sending mail)     Encrypted - TLS/STARTTLS    465
SMTP (sending mail)     Encrypted - SSL             465
SMTP (sending mail)     Unencrypted                 25* (or 26)

POP3 (receiving mail)   Encrypted - TLS             995
POP3 (receiving mail)   Encrypted - SSL             995
POP3 (receiving mail)   Unencrypted                 110
IMAP (receiving mail)   Encrypted - TLS             993
IMAP (receiving mail)   Encrypted - SSL             993
IMAP (receiving mail)   Unencrypted                 143
```

https://billing.precedence.com.au/billing/knowledgebase/70/Mail-Ports-for-POP3-IMAP-and-SMTP.html

Comment: I've added my `.env` you could see my setup is correct.

Comment: 1. I'm sure AWS won't let you use port 25 since it's insecure. Use 465 instead. 
2. You can also use the SES driver instead of SMTP.

Added  ports in my response